# Multiple Django projects on one domain under sub urls using NGINX and proxy_pass

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django app on mydomain.com/. I want to have another app on, lets say, mydomain.com/staging/.

1st app: mydomain.com/
2nd app: mydomain.com/staging/

How do I configure it in Nginx and Django?
After this

```
location ~* ^/staging/ {
rewrite ^/staging/(.*) /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:18000;
}
```

I still have my 2nd app redirect me to my 1st app. When I use mydomain.com/staging/admin/, it redirects me to mydomain.com/admin/, and every URI I use does the same. What is the proper way of configuring multiple sub-url Django apps?